# Parse.com Cloud Code custom method call result undefined

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've got an `afterSave` handler in Cloud Code that conditionally calls a custom method.

From my testing, both functions appear to be working exactly as desired. The custom method is skipped appropriately (with confirming console messages looking correct). It is also called appropriately, and the custom method creates a new object exactly as desired.

What's confusing me is that when the custom method **IS** called, I get something like the following in my Cloud Code log:

```
Input: {"title":"title","ownerId":"ownerId"}
Result: undefined
```

Like I said, the values seem to be passed in correctly, and the method seems to run correctly, but I don't understand why I get `Result: undefined`.

In the method that is called, I've placed a `response.success()` or `response.error()` in every pathway that's possible.

So, is this something to worry about?

The custom method is a "fire-and-forget" type of method, so my `afterSave` method doesn't wait around for a response. Is that why I'm getting `Result: undefined`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting `undefined` is because your response and error functions don't pass any values. Replace it with this.

```
success: function(result) {
    //...
    response.success(result);
},
error: function(error) {
    response.error(error);
}
```

Then you'll no longer have an `undefined` result.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really don't want to return anything, but still don't want the response to be "undefined", you can do response.success({});

Comment: Ah, ok. I was doing `response.error(error)`, but just `response.success()`. That's great to know! So, just a `response.success('success')` seems like a good solution, then, right?

Comment: Yup, that would work! You can respond with anything you'd like.